# YUI TabView.get("tabs") => null: race condition?

Tags: yui, tabs

Inside my "dom ready" function, I create a TabView on an HTML element and call tabview.getTab(0).blah(). Unfortunately every now and then I get an error that tabView.get("tabs") returned null in my javascript console (firefox).

```
        YAHOO.util.Event.onDOMReady(function() {
      tabview = new YAHOO.widget.TabView("content");
      var tab0 = tabview.getTab(0);
          ...
```

tabview.getTab(0) is implemented as tabs.get("tabs")[0].

This happens sometimes but not every time. Does anybody have an explanation for why this happens sometimes? The DOMReady event occurs after the entire DOM is in place but before anything is displayed, right?

Speaking of which, sometimes I see flashing of data in some of the other tabs. That does not bode well I think for the nice, clean experience I was hoping for.

This is YUI 2.7.0/

Answer (score 0):

OK - I believe the answer is, I was trying to use prototype and YUI at the same time. In theory I think that is possible but you need to pick one or the other when it comes to doing things on the "dom:loaded"/onDOMReady events, if you know what I mean.

So I don't know what was happening, but it was some sort of race, and once I picked a single mechanism for doing things when the dom was ready, everything is working fine.